# google Map loads without data connection

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm almost new to android, so I'm trying to make a map activity; for this, I followed the demo from Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro
So, the map works without any problem, but I noticed a weird behavior, when I install the map on my cell phone and turn on the airplane mode (Wifi and 4g are off), the map still loads. How is this possible? I thought that the application downloads the map through data (4g or wifi). Is it possible that my application is loading the map from Google play services? Here is the code.

```
package com.example.startup;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.R.layout;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.LayoutParams;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Navigation extends FragmentActivity implements
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener  {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    int ZOOM = 13;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    ArrayList<Location> MyLocation;
    private RadioButton layer;
    boolean show_statsEnable=false;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    int navigation_number=4;
    float speed=0;
    float distance=0;
    float elapsed_time=0;
    boolean showing=false;
    Location myLocation = null;
    PopupWindow popwin=null;
    RelativeLayout show_stats=null;
    TextView navigation_speed=null;
    boolean navigation_trackEnable=false;
    List<LatLng> LatLngArray = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    boolean navigation_ShowStatsEnable=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.navigation);

        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this,this,this);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }


        }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        mLocationClient.connect();
//        mLocationClient.setMockMode(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
        }
        if (mMap != null) 
        {
            setUpMap();    
    }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);    
    }
    private void update_map(){
//      Toast.makeText(this, "Zoom "+String.valueOf(ZOOM) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try{
            myLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();                  
            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
            LatLng myPosition=null;
            myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
//          CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, ZOOM);
//          mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(myPosition)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                .zoom(ZOOM)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(0)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);
        locationRequest.setInterval(0).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mLocationListener);     
    }   
    private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        private long mLastEventTime = 0;

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {        
            update_map();           

    };

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }        
}
```

Any comment will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: your map is showing because it is stored internally... it is using de google-maps API... and works just like google maps app... it will render the map without connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the deal...

The map shows because it has been cached by the phone. This means that the phone has downloaded a bit of a map for faster loading (in the same way your browser might download part of a frequently visited website, so that to load the website, it doesn't have to spend so much time downloading the HTML and other stuff). As such, no data connection is needed.

What you may find (personally, I find this cool) is that, even when you are viewing an uncached map (or rather, viewing an empty screen) the map may still be able to locate your position. This is because the phone uses GPS or GLONASS (depending on where you live) to locate you, regardless of whether or not there is data.

By scrolling away from the map part displayed when on airplane mode,  you will probably see a blank screen, confirming that it is cached.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is `Cached` map tiles that were downloaded when you first had a connection. If you move the map to a different point on the globe that you have not visited you will see that the map does not load